# Fix year leap bug when adding month php

Tags: php, date, datetime, leap-year

When a datetime object has date '2012-01-30', we have the following object:

```
object(DateTime)#1233 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-30 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(9) "ETC/GMT+3"
}
```

But, when a month is added:

```
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

It will result the following object:

```
object(DateTime)#1233 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-03-01 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(9) "ETC/GMT+3"
}
```

It should add a month, so the date to be displayed should be 
'2012-02-28', therefore february of 2012, instead of march of 2012.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Note that this "overflow" or "rollover" behavior is part of the design.  See [it described in Example #3 in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).  It's common in other languages as well, but IMHO it's a bad design - for the reason you illustrated.  Also, it's only a leap-year issue in that Feb 2012 had 29 days.  It's still an issue for *any* month of *any* year, where the number of days in the resulting month is less than the days part of the origin date.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function add($date_str, $months)
{
    $date = new DateTime($date_str);
    $start_day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+{$months} month");
    $end_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($start_day != $end_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date;
}

$result = add('2011-01-31', 1);  // 2011-02-28
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, but I think there is probably a way that doesn't need formatting or natural language parsing as well.